# Validation, Interpretation and Post-hoc testing with a zero-truncated GLMM (using glmmTMB, DHARMa and emmeans)

Tags: interpretation, glmm, lsmeans, glmmtmb

I tried to go as far on my own as I could. But after 6 months of searching and reading, I'm still unsure if everything I did is statistically sound. Unfortunately, I neither have a statistican nor statistical trained peers to talk to. Hence, I ask here, any bit of help or guidance is much appreciated.
I have several questions concering my model, the validation and some interpretation. I'll try to structure these questions according to my realized steps (using R).

## General information

I conducted a field study concerning insect oviposition in several trap types. My main interest was if there are differences in the binary response (proportion of postive traps) and differences of the amount (count data) between trap types. These were also my planned contrasts for the post-hoc tests. Further the influence of temperature and relative humidity on presence and amount were of interest.

The independent variables for the model are:

1. `Site`: Factor with levels X and Y, two study locations
2. `Species`: Factor with levels O and P (only two species were found)
3. `Treatment`: Factor with 7 levels (A-G), these are the trap types
4. `Plot`: Factor with 30 levels, 15 Plots per Site (X1-X15; Y1-15), each Plot was a group of all 7 trap types
5. `Date_new`: Factor with 18 levels (1-18), weekly visits to inspect the traps
6. `mean_temp`: continous, recorded mean temperature
7. `mean_rh`: continous, recorded mean relative humidity

The dependent variable is `Amount`: Counts of insects caught in traps.
Small sample of the data frame I'm using:

```
   Amount Plot  Treatment Species Site  Date_new mean_temp mean_rh
    <dbl> <fct> <fct>     <fct>   <fct> <fct>        <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     40 Y2    A         P       Y     7             19.8    75.7
 2      0 Y7    B         P       Y     3             21.4    70.1
 3      0 X5    G         P       X     12            16.6    95.6
 4      0 Y5    G         P       Y     2             18.4    78.6
 5      0 X14   G         P       X     13            19.9    91.9
 6      0 Y12   D         O       Y     8             17.8    95.0
 7      0 X4    F         P       X     16            10.9    95.9
 8      0 X11   E         O       X     8             16.6    98.0
 9      0 X9    G         P       X     11            16.4    98.1
10      0 Y13   D         P       Y     12            17.6    93.4
11      0 Y13   G         P       Y     8             17.8    95.0
12      0 X8    C         O       X     2             17.1    82.9
13      0 X1    B         O       X     12            16.6    95.6
14     16 X6    A         P       X     10            18.7    90.4
15      0 Y8    F         O       Y     14            16.9    96.4
16    271 Y15   B         P       Y     4             21.5    81.0
17      4 X14   D         O       X     11            16.4    98.1
18      0 X4    A         P       X     14            15.7    98.0
19      0 Y12   E         P       Y     15            14.2    94.3
20      0 X13   C         P       X     10            18.7    90.4
```

---

## Dataset "problems"

My data has a lot of zeroes (4410 zeroes vs. 501 positive counts). On `Site` Y `Species` O had only 15 positive counts (vs 169 on `Site` X), further on `Site` Y three trap types never had any positive counts for `Species` O. Further due to destruction,theft and other events, the replications for trap types are not equal.
Some boxplots (with `Amount` including/excluding zeroes).[image: Boxplots]

---

## zero truncated negative-binomial GLMM

For my model I used the following code:

```
mod<-glmmTMB(Amount~Treatment*Species+Species*mean_temp+Species*mean_rh+
(1|Site)+(1|Plot)+(1|Date_new),
data=x, ziformula=~., dispformula=~1, family="truncated_nbinom2")
```

A few notes:
As early iterations did not converge, I omitted visits(Date_new) for each Species respectively, were not one single individual was caught.

I am interested in influence of Treatment, mean_temp and mean_rh, but as I know that both species could differ ecologially, interactions were added. Site, Plot and Date were used as random factors as they were a tool for replication and they're of no further interest (maybe Date for phenological aspects, but this should be captured with the climatic variables). This formula was explicitly used for both model parts.

The summary gives this output:

```
 Family: truncated_nbinom2  ( log )
Formula:          Amount ~ Treatment * Species + Species * mean_temp + Species *  
    mean_rh + (1 | Site) + (1 | Plot) + (1 | Date_new)
Zero inflation:          ~.
Data: x

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  7359.3   7638.8  -3636.7   7273.3     4868 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Site     (Intercept) 0.04665  0.2160  
 Plot     (Intercept) 0.05434  0.2331  
 Date_new (Intercept) 0.23834  0.4882  
Number of obs: 4911, groups:  Site, 2; Plot, 30; Date_new, 18

Zero-inflation model:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Site     (Intercept) 0.05825  0.2414  
 Plot     (Intercept) 0.16314  0.4039  
 Date_new (Intercept) 0.29113  0.5396  
Number of obs: 4911, groups:  Site, 2; Plot, 30; Date_new, 18

Overdispersion parameter for truncated_nbinom2 family (): 0.765 

Conditional model:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -1.70902    3.54067  -0.483  0.62932    
TreatmentB          -1.64219    0.23980  -6.848 7.49e-12 ***
TreatmentC           0.64610    0.26293   2.457  0.01400 *  
TreatmentD           0.29868    0.24932   1.198  0.23092    
TreatmentE          -0.95049    0.44411  -2.140  0.03234 *  
TreatmentF          -2.18361    0.93974  -2.324  0.02015 *  
TreatmentG          -0.56957    0.33220  -1.715  0.08643 .  
SpeciesP             5.44365    2.66339   2.044  0.04097 *  
mean_temp            0.13500    0.07860   1.718  0.08586 .  
mean_rh              0.02941    0.02695   1.091  0.27512    
TreatmentB:SpeciesP  0.86735    0.32642   2.657  0.00788 ** 
TreatmentC:SpeciesP  0.24724    0.32737   0.755  0.45010    
TreatmentD:SpeciesP  0.31674    0.32108   0.987  0.32389    
TreatmentE:SpeciesP -0.36467    0.67367  -0.541  0.58829    
TreatmentF:SpeciesP  0.88982    1.16333   0.765  0.44434    
TreatmentG:SpeciesP  0.43861    0.46233   0.949  0.34278    
SpeciesP:mean_temp   0.08004    0.07273   1.101  0.27111    
SpeciesP:mean_rh    -0.07658    0.01930  -3.968 7.25e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Zero-inflation model:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          7.17614    2.52254   2.845 0.004444 ** 
TreatmentB           0.70285    0.21567   3.259 0.001119 ** 
TreatmentC           0.94747    0.23752   3.989 6.64e-05 ***
TreatmentD           0.77291    0.23073   3.350 0.000808 ***
TreatmentE           2.25256    0.37052   6.079 1.21e-09 ***
TreatmentF           3.65116    0.72626   5.027 4.97e-07 ***
TreatmentG           1.84414    0.29402   6.272 3.56e-10 ***
SpeciesP             1.19068    2.27678   0.523 0.600996    
mean_temp           -0.11158    0.06350  -1.757 0.078871 .  
mean_rh             -0.04186    0.01958  -2.137 0.032559 *  
TreatmentB:SpeciesP -0.09642    0.29565  -0.326 0.744327    
TreatmentC:SpeciesP -0.98618    0.30602  -3.223 0.001270 ** 
TreatmentD:SpeciesP -0.67605    0.30343  -2.228 0.025878 *  
TreatmentE:SpeciesP  0.26768    0.57151   0.468 0.639518    
TreatmentF:SpeciesP -0.62174    0.94026  -0.661 0.508461    
TreatmentG:SpeciesP -0.08752    0.40392  -0.217 0.828451    
SpeciesP:mean_temp  -0.25265    0.06105  -4.139 3.50e-05 ***
SpeciesP:mean_rh     0.04205    0.01655   2.540 0.011085 *
```

---

## Model validation with DHARMa and performance

Using following code, I tried to check for problems:

```
performance::check_collinearity(mod)
mod_sim <-simulateResiduals(mod,seed=123, n=4000, plot=T)
```

Collinearity check output:

```
* conditional component:
Low Correlation
 Parameter  VIF Increased SE
 mean_temp 2.07         1.44
   mean_rh 2.93         1.71

High Correlation
         Parameter    VIF Increased SE
         Treatment 139.08        11.79
           Species 358.22        18.93
 Treatment:Species 242.98        15.59
 Species:mean_temp  90.30         9.50
   Species:mean_rh 152.79        12.36

* zero inflated component: 
Low Correlation
 Parameter  VIF Increased SE
 mean_temp 1.50         1.22
   mean_rh 1.83         1.35

High Correlation
         Parameter    VIF Increased SE
         Treatment 124.86        11.17
           Species 420.56        20.51
 Treatment:Species 249.82        15.81
 Species:mean_temp 103.80        10.19
   Species:mean_rh 178.82        13.37

Warning:
Model has interaction terms. VIFs might be inflated. You may check multicollinearity among predictors of a model without interaction terms.
```

Inflation through the interactions was expected, a model without interactions resulted in only "low correlations" (VIFs<2).

Further the simulation from DHARMa showed no problems (as I understand the red line on the right side plot should not be a concern?)[image]

## post-hoc testing

(edit: removed "sqrt()^2"-structurce from code, thanks @Russ Lenth)

Using emmeans and the following code, I obtained my pairwise comparisons between all trap types

```
VarCorr(mod)
total_SD_cond = sqrt(VarCorr(mod)$cond$Plot[[1]][1]+
                     VarCorr(mod)$cond$Date_new[[1]][1]+
                     VarCorr(mod)$cond$Site[[1]][1]
)

**edit: error in code ($cond$Site instead of $zi$Site)**
total_SD_zi = sqrt(VarCorr(mod)$zi$Plot[[1]][1]+
                   VarCorr(mod)$zi$Date_new[[1]][1]+
                   VarCorr(mod)$zi$Site[[1]][1]
)

    
pairs(emmeans(mod, ~Treatment|Species, component="zi"),type="response", 
        bias.adjust=TRUE, sigma = total_SD_zi, adj="fdr", infer=(TRUE))
pairs(emmeans(mod, ~Treatment|Species, component="cond"),type="response", 
      bias.adjust=TRUE, sigma = total_SD_cond, adj="fdr", infer=(TRUE))
```

To save space, small snippets of the comparisons,

for the binomial part:

```
edit: adjustment of results due to coding error
Species = O:
 contrast odds.ratio     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 A / B        0.6221 0.1342 4868  0.32294    1.198 -3.259  0.0017 
 A / C        0.4871 0.1157 4868  0.23662    1.003 -3.989  0.0002 
 A / D        0.5800 0.1338 4868  0.28763    1.169 -3.350  0.0014 
...
Species = P:
 contrast odds.ratio     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 A / B        0.6850 0.1387 4868  0.37026    1.267 -2.996  0.0041 
 A / C        1.3058 0.2539 4868  0.72320    2.358  0.199  0.8422 
 A / D        1.1403 0.2266 4868  0.62332    2.086 -0.487  0.6572 
...
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: bonferroni method for 21 estimates 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log odds ratio scale 
P value adjustment: fdr method for 21 tests 
Tests are performed on the log odds ratio scale 
Bias adjustment applied based on sigma = 0.71591
```

for the count part:

```
Species = O:
 contrast  ratio      SE   df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 A / B     6.043  1.4491 4868   2.9153   12.526  6.848  <.0001 
 A / C     0.613  0.1612 4868   0.2757    1.363 -2.457  0.0295 
 A / D     0.868  0.2163 4868   0.4066    1.851 -1.198  0.2553 
    ...
Species = P:
 contrast  ratio      SE   df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 A / B     2.538  0.5748 4868   1.2753    5.053  3.422  0.0022 
 A / C     0.479  0.0958 4868   0.2606    0.879 -4.465  0.0001 
 A / D     0.632  0.1304 4868   0.3377    1.183 -2.984  0.0067 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: bonferroni method for 21 estimates 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale 
P value adjustment: fdr method for 21 tests 
Tests are performed on the log scale 
Bias adjustment applied based on sigma = 0.58252
```

Further to test the slopes of mean_temp and mean_rh using emtrends (emmeans package):

```
emtrends(mod,  component="zi",  ~ Species, var="mean_temp", infer=c(TRUE))
emtrends(mod,component="cond",  ~ Species, var="mean_temp", infer=c(TRUE))
emtrends(mod,  component="zi",  ~ Species,   var="mean_rh", infer=c(TRUE))
emtrends(mod,component="cond",  ~ Species,   var="mean_rh", infer=c(TRUE))

 Species mean_temp.trend     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 O                -0.112 0.0635 4868   -0.236   0.0129 -1.757  0.0789 
 P                -0.364 0.0752 4868   -0.512  -0.2168 -4.842  <.0001 

 Species mean_temp.trend     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 O                 0.135 0.0786 4868  -0.0191    0.289 1.718   0.0859 
 P                 0.215 0.0976 4868   0.0237    0.406 2.203   0.0276 

 Species mean_rh.trend     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 O           -0.041857 0.0196 4868  -0.0802 -0.00347 -2.137  0.0326 
 P            0.000188 0.0184 4868  -0.0359  0.03632  0.010  0.9918 

 Species mean_rh.trend     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value 
 O              0.0294 0.0269 4868  -0.0234  0.08224  1.091  0.2752 
 P             -0.0472 0.0234 4868  -0.0930 -0.00139 -2.020  0.0434 

Results are averaged over the levels of: Treatment 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

---

## Finally Interpretation

### Treatment effects

This is relatively straight forward (I hope): Odds.ratios <1 in the binomial part, show that the left side shows more presence than the right side (as extra zeroes are modeled, therefore higher odds show higher absence and odds.ratios == 1 show equality)

Ratios>1 in the conditional part show that the left side shows higher counts than the right side.
(See Questions)

### Trends

For Species P, mean_temp showed a positive association with presence (negative association with absence is calculated) and counts. In addition a weak(?) negative association of counts and mean_rh.

For Species O, only presence seems to be positively associated with mean_rh.

---

---

## Questions

1. Should I be concerned regarding `Species` O and `Site` Y as some trap types were never positive? Or is this no problem with GLMMs (as I suspect, according to my literature research)
2. Am I right in assuming that the unbalanced replications don't matter in my GLMM?
3. Is the model structure correct? Especially the non-nesting of Site/Plot? (As Plot has unique labelling for each Site)
4. Are my interpretations concerning the Treatment effect and the Trends correct?
5. I'm not completely sure concerning the interpretation of the (odds).ratios. For example the comparison of A/B for Species O: 0.6221, indicates that the modelled event (in this case zeroes, hence absence) has a lower chance of occurence in A compared to B. Is this correct?
6. Concerning the interpretation of the ratios (count part), again with A/B for Species O: 6.043, indicates that A has a *relative* higher effect than B. Is this correct?

### Edit (14.03.2021): Addition of emmeans output

```
emmeans(mod, ~Treatment|Species, component="zi",type="response",
   bias.adjust=TRUE, sigma = total_SD_zi, adj="fdr")

Species = O:
 Treatment response      SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 A            0.787 0.04184 4868    0.657    0.880
 B            0.878 0.02932 4868    0.777    0.938
 C            0.901 0.02605 4868    0.808    0.953
 D            0.885 0.02908 4868    0.783    0.944
 E            0.971 0.01177 4868    0.916    0.990
 F            0.993 0.00556 4868    0.947    0.999
 G            0.956 0.01431 4868    0.898    0.982

Species = P:
 Treatment response      SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 A            0.865 0.03028 4868    0.763    0.928
 B            0.920 0.02039 4868    0.846    0.961
 C            0.860 0.03172 4868    0.754    0.927
 D            0.875 0.02937 4868    0.775    0.936
 E            0.987 0.00609 4868    0.955    0.996
 F            0.992 0.00488 4868    0.959    0.999
 G            0.973 0.00900 4868    0.935    0.989

emmeans(mod, ~Treatment|Species, component="cond",type="response", 
      bias.adjust=TRUE, sigma = total_SD_cond, adj="fdr")

Species = O:
 Treatment response    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 A            31.58  8.19 4868   15.713     63.5
 B             6.11  1.77 4868    2.799     13.4
 C            60.27 18.65 4868   26.203    138.6
 D            42.58 12.76 4868   19.007     95.4
 E            12.21  5.77 4868    3.421     43.6
 F             3.56  3.40 4868    0.273     46.4
 G            17.87  6.69 4868    6.520     49.0

Species = P:
 Treatment response    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 A            29.54  7.59 4868   14.790     59.0
 B            13.61  3.94 4868    6.239     29.7
 C            72.16 19.05 4868   35.458    146.9
 D            54.65 14.84 4868   26.320    113.5
 E             7.93  4.41 4868    1.775     35.4
 F             8.10  6.02 4868    1.097     59.8
 G            25.91  9.64 4868    9.522     70.5
```

### Second edit: Calculation of odds.ratios

After finding this comment by @RussLenth:

> No. The odds of something equals p/(1-p): the probably of occurring divided by the probability of not occurring. So the odds ratio you refer to is [pA/(1-pA)] / [pB/(1-pB)]. Note that odds equal to 1 (“even odds”) is equivalent to p equals 1/2. – Russ Lenth Aug 19 '19 at 19:22

I tried the following for the example given in my question 5:

```
Odds for Species O for trap A: 0.787
Odds for Species O for trap B: 0.878

(0.787/(1-0.787)) / (0.878/(1-0.878)) = 0.5134054
```

Which is not what I get from the output (0.6221). Does this difference come from the back-transformations? (As the tests are performed on the log odds)

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you use sqrt(...)^2 in each term of the total SD calculations, rather than just adding those variances? Also, instead of asking questions 5 and 6, SHOW the answers to those questions by displaying emmeans(..., type = "response")

Comment: Dear @RussLenth, thanks for your reply. Answering your first question, I don't know what I did there, this definitely false, I blame a kind of tunnel vision; corrected the code in the question. To your second question: Maybe I'm not understanding your question right, but both results mentioned in questions 5 and 6 are shown in my post (see code blocks 5 and 6). Or do you miss the rest of these outputs?

Comment: Reading again, I think you're refering to the emmeans(...,type="response") output without comparisons? I added this in a further edit.

Comment: Right, you can look at the actual values and know which is higher or lower.